# How to green Marked tag Number or String as Text Javascript

Tags: javascript, xlsx

**I want to create a XLSX sheet in which every cell has green marked Number and other values stored as text.**

I achieved the text with this code but was not able to mark green Mark

```
function exportExcel(response) {

    const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    const worksheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(response);

   
    response.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
        row.forEach((cell, colIndex) => {
            const cellObj = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ r: rowIndex, c: colIndex });

            worksheet[cellObj]={
                t:'s',
                v:cell.toString(),
                z:'@'
            }
        });
    });

    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'Sheet1');
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'refund.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: Use ```s``` property in the cell object.